# Attach both pdf and excel files to an email on single click in VBA

Tags: vba

I have VBA code to create pdf file in excel and attache to email on button click. i am wondering if it is possible to attach both pdf and excel file to an email on single click.
please find below code which i am trying to modify.. bold section showing two functions. any suggestion or help greatly appreciated !! Thanks

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim EmailSubject As String, EmailSignature As String
Dim Email_Body   As String
Dim olMailItem As Object
'Dim olFormatHTML As Form
Dim objMail As Object
Dim CurrentMonth As String, DestFolder As String, PDFFile As String
Dim Email_To As String, Email_CC As String, Email_BCC As String
Dim OpenPDFAfterCreating As Boolean, AlwaysOverwritePDF As Boolean, DisplayEmail As Boolean
Dim OverwritePDF As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim OutlookApp As Object, OutlookMail As Object
'CurrentMonth = ""
Dim fName As String, eCode1 As String, eCode2 As String, fNameLong As String

' *****************************************************
' *****     You Can Change These Variables    *********


'Create excel
 fName = "User Access request:"
eCode1 = Sheet1.Range("B7").Value
eCode2 = Range("B7").Value
fNameLong = fName & " " & eCode1 & " - " & eCode2


    EmailSubject = "abs"   'Change this to change the subject of the email. The current month is added to end of subj line
    OpenPDFAfterCreating = False    'Change this if you want to open the PDF after creating it : TRUE or FALSE
    AlwaysOverwritePDF = True    'Change this if you always want to overwrite a PDF that already exists :TRUE or FALSE
    DisplayEmail = True 'Change this if you don't want to display the email before sending.  Note, you must have a TO email address specified for this to work
    Email_To = "abc" 'Change this if you want to specify To email e.g. ActiveSheet.Range("H1") to get email from cell H1
    Email_CC = "xyz.com"
    Email_BCC = ""


    'Create the PDF
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterCreating

 **

    'Create an Outlook object and new mail message
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application") 'Dialogs (DialogSendMail).Show ")
        Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    'Create excel file but to another email    
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show "xyz", fNameLong

**

    'Display email and specify To, Subject, etc
    With OutlookMail

        .Display
        .To = Email_To
        .Cc = Email_CC
        .BCC = Email_BCC
        .Subject = EmailSubject & CurrentMonth
        .Attachments.Add PDFFile

        If DisplayEmail = False Then

            .Send

        End If

    End With

  End Sub
```

Comment: Hi can anybudy help me on this ? the below line have added but its not working .Attachments.Add "[Excel File Path Goes Here]" 'Add this line

Answer (score 0):

```
With OutlookMail

    .Display
    .To = Email_To
    .Cc = Email_CC
    .BCC = Email_BCC
    .Subject = EmailSubject & CurrentMonth
    .Attachments.Add PDFFile
    .Attachments.Add "[Excel File Path Goes Here]" 'Add this line

    If DisplayEmail = False Then

        .Send

    End If

End With
```

Comment: Hi, i made the changes as said above and provided excel path but still its not working .. i am only  getting PDF attachment

Comment: Hi can anybudy help me on this ? the below line have added but its not working  .Attachments.Add "[Excel File Path Goes Here]" 'Add this line

Comment: "[Excel File Path Goes Here]" is to be replaced with your actual file path. In your code you can use `ThisWorkbook.FullName` to provide this as a variable - so this line of code will read `.Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.FullName`